# Tomcat6 not applying changes from deployed WAR file

Tags: deployment, tomcat6

Assume app `myapp` that is under Tomcat's `webapps`.  It is deployed there via `myapp.war`, which is dropped in `webapps`.  The most usual form of deployment.

However, after I make changes to a WAR constituent (e.g. a JSP) and redeploy the WAR (making sure the change made it into the WAR by expanding the archive after it was dropped in webapps), I start the server and the changes do not get deployed to the `myapp` final directory.  If I delete the dir altogether, the change makes it in but but when I am just updating.

Does anybody have any idea why this bug is ocurring and what I need to do to remedy this deployment nuissance?

Answer (score 0):

Into your project directory within webapp inter into the module directory (rename-to='module_name') and delete all files but don't delete directories